# Why can't I read a JSON file with a different program while my Processing sketch is still open?

Tags: json, processing

I'm writing data to a JSON file in Processing with the saveJSONObject command. I would like to access that JSON file with another program (MAX/MSP) while my sketch is still open. The problem is, MAX is unable to read from the file while my sketch is running. Only after I close the sketch is MAX able to import data from my file.

Is Processing keeping that file open somehow while the sketch is running? Is there any way I can get around this problem?

Comment: On which operating system? Give more details (ans also some code) so **edit your question**

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to stream your data straight to MaxMSP using the OSC protocol. On the Processing side, have a look at the [oscP5 library](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/oscP5/) and on the Max side at the [udpreceive](https://docs.cycling74.com/max5/refpages/max-ref/udpreceive.html) object.

You could send your JSON object as a string and unpack that in Max (maybe using the JavaScript support already present in Max), but it might be simpler to mimic the structure of your JSON object as the arguments of the OSC message object which you simply umpack in Max directly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, because I/O is usually [buffered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) (notably for performance reasons, ans also because the hardware is doing I/O by blocks).

Try to flush the output channel, perhaps using [PrintWriter::flush](https://processing.org/reference/PrintWriter_flush_.html) or something similar.

Details are implementation specific (and might be operating system specific).